# Quantum mechanics representations $x$, $p$, and not $(x,p)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wigner-transform

In Quantum Mechanics, generally speaking we work with space representation $\Psi(x)$ and/or the momentum representation $\Psi(p)$ of wavefunctions. Are there representations with mixing of $(x,p)$, i.e., is there any $\Psi(x,p)$ representation in Quantum Mechanics?

Comment: Would the [Wigner phase space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) fit what you are after?

Comment: see [Wigner quasi-distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) and the tag [tag:wigner-transform] on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Schrödinger equation for phase space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280969/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a representation/framework that includes both conjugate variables.  It's called the Wigner Distribution and is a quasiprobability distribution.   You may want to google it.